# How to configure/allow connection on port 443 on a sagmaker training instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker, aws-security-group

I'm running training using sagemaker pipeline steps inside sagemaker studio. I have set AppNetworkAccessType to vcp only (sample cloudformation below) . within studio, i able to connec to our github server- hosted internally and download and run my training code. I am following this example here - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-experiments-dvc-demo/blob/main/dvc_sagemaker_script_mode.ipynb, which downloads the repo on the instance the training/pre-processing is running on -> https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-experiments-dvc-demo/blob/main/source_dir/preprocessing-experiment.py#L37. when i run this code , i get connection timeout on port 443, can't connect to mycompany.github. so from my notebook instance, i can connect to my github repo, but not from my training/processing instance that sagemaker spins up behind the scene . is there a way to configure and allow connection to that port from the training instance that sagemaker spins up?

```
Resources:
   sgDomain:
      Type: AWS::SageMaker::Domain
      Properties: 
        AppNetworkAccessType: VpcOnly
        ...
```

Comment: For SageMaker training when creating the estimator you can configure the git_repo as per your requirement. Please refer the documentation - https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html -> git_config